# CakePHP 3 creating XML view

Tags: xml, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to convert an array to an XML response. The objective is to write a function within a plugin controller and call it, which would return an XML response.

I've been trying this below mentioned code from the CakePHP manual.

```
   namespace App\Controller;

   class ArticlesController extends AppController{

       public function initialize(){
            parent::initialize();
            $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
       }

       public function index(){

            // Set the view vars that have to be serialized.
            $this->set('articles', $this->paginate());
            // Specify which view vars JsonView should serialize.
            $this->set('_serialize', ['articles']);
       }
    }
```

Is there a way I can debug or pr the response and see how exactly the XML response will look like?

Comment: You need to be careful with technical terms, what exactly are you referring to with "_response_"? The HTTP response, or the rendered data view content?

Comment: I meant HTTP response.

Comment: Ok, and why do you need to do that in your application? Can't you just use your browsers network console and inspect the actual received response?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator Did you try printing the $this->response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in routes.php, insert

```
Router::extensions('xml');
```

just before

```
Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');
```

then, just use ".xml" in yout action:

/yourController/index.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am new in cakePhp, and using cackephp 3 (v 3.5). In my case just adding
`Router::extensions('xml');`

to the routes.php didn't help.
I have used more complex solution, but it works fine.
In my SitemapController controller (/src/controller/SitemapController.php):

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Routing\Router;

class SitemapController extends AppController 
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        // Set the response Content-Type to xml for each action
        $this->response->type(['xml' => 'application/xml']);       
        $this->response = $this->response->withType('xml');        
        // set layout 
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');                
    } 

    /**
     * Shows index sitemap, which contains all the site's sitemaps (like pages)
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // ... some code here

        // just set the view vars to show in XML
        $this->set('baseUrl', Router::url('', true));
    }
// ... other code here
}
```

I have set response type as XML and set cacke's ajax layout - /src/Template/Layout/ajax.ctp (it only contains echo operator):

```
echo $this->fetch('content');
```

In my routes.php file

```
// sitemap index
Router::scope(
    '/sitemap.xml',
    ['controller' => 'Sitemap'],
    function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect(
            '/', 
            ['action' => 'index']
        );              
    }
);
```

Almost in the same way it works for json type of content.