# XML View in Cakephp 3

Tags: xml, cakephp-3.x

I am using Cakephp 3 and on every view I can use the .xml extension and it shows all the objects which the action gives to the view. How can I prevent that? I don´t want the user to see that (prevent Screen Scraping etc.)

Comment: Then why do set view variables that you don't want to output in the first place?

Comment: I am not recalling that I set them anyways. I just found out, because I am testing an Sitemap Plugin. This was in my AppController:

`public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        /*if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }*/
    }`

Comment: Please see detailed description on my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102199/cakephp-3-creating-xml-view/46466498#46466498. Hope this can help